# how do I get $(this),val() in the function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input at the onfocus event, when triggered, the getValue() function is called, in which I try to get the value of this input while it is in focus

```php
<input type="text" onfocus="getValue()" name="title" id="title" class=" form__control" value="<?=$row_title['TITLE'] ?>">
}
```

```js
function getValue() {
  before_value = $(this).val();
  console.log(before_value);
}
```

unfortunately, this error occurs when executing my code:

*jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')*

Comment: There is no call to `toLowerCase()` in the code you show, thus, the error is not from that code-piece ...

Comment: I don't use such a function anywhere at all in the project

Comment: when I remove $(this).val(), and I write console.log("hello") - everything works fine

Comment: You have to set the `this`-context explicitly: `onfocus="getValue.call(this)"` otherwise `this` (within your getValue function) will point to the global `window` object instead.

Comment: This is not defined. You have to study how this works or use function.call / function.apply to solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getValue() {
  before_value = $(this).val();
  console.log(before_value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onfocus="getValue.call(this)" name="title" id="title" class=" form__control" value="<?=$row_title['TITLE'] ?>">
```

Comment: I don't need an id, I wouldn't ask such a question then.I need exactly $(this), for a universal approach
, since further in the project I add blocks and the id change
, I need to get the input value when focusing on it

Comment: Please, check the code.